# Classification Model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

While building a classification model in R on a dataset with many independent variables, how can you find out which variables should and should not be included in the model?

Comment: This is pretty involved, and there are different strategies. This is known as `feature subset selection`

Answer (score 0):

There are a quite a few algorithms available to do feature selection. You can try rfe from the caret package. The tougher part is deciding the metric by which to keep the variables.

For example below, I use a dataset Ionosphere, and I added 30 random variables that have nothing to do with the dependent variable, and run recursive feature elimination. First the data:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(e1071)
data(Ionosphere)
set.seed(888)
# exclude first 2 columns
Data = Ionosphere[,-c(1:2)]
# introduce another 30 columns that are random
Data = cbind(Class=Data[,"Class"],Data[-ncol(Data)],
             matrix(rnorm(nrow(Data)*30),ncol=30)
)
```

I select the smallest size that is within 1.5% of the maximum Accuracy:

```
svmFuncs = caretFuncs
svmFuncs$selectSize = pickSizeTolerance

rfe.ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = svmFuncs,
                       method="repeatedcv",
                       number=5,repeats=3)
```

We run it use rfe from caret:

```
test = rfe(Data[,-1],
           Data$Class,
    sizes = seq(5,50,by=5),
    rfeControl = rfe.ctrl,method="svmLinear")
```

Results:

```
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 3 times) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

 Variables Accuracy  Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
         5   0.8214 0.5857    0.04111 0.09904         
        10   0.8328 0.6156    0.02787 0.06535        *
        15   0.8385 0.6263    0.03413 0.08129         
        20   0.8291 0.6031    0.03215 0.07959         
        25   0.8319 0.6100    0.03647 0.08981         
        30   0.8253 0.5962    0.03363 0.08314         
        35   0.8272 0.6022    0.03354 0.08179         
        40   0.8271 0.6042    0.03579 0.08845         
        45   0.8243 0.6008    0.03511 0.08086         
        50   0.8138 0.5795    0.03447 0.07868         
        62   0.8092 0.5685    0.02800 0.06212 



test$optVariables
 [1] "V3"  "V7"  "V27" "V5"  "V33" "V31" "V9"  "V8"  "V15" "V29"
```

From the results above, you might choose 15 or 25, so it really depends on your data and what you want to achieve with the model in the end.